# Issue to connect the mysql from ubuntu server using database management tool

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-server

My UBUNTU server version 18.04.1 and mysql version is 5.7.22 , its working fine. I created database users and provided all privileges to the Users. I changed the bind address 0.0.0.0 in mysql.cnf and connet TCP - 3306 port

Everything I did to connect the database using tools in remote access.

Still its not connected and database management tool shows error like the driver has not received any packets from the server.

ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'XXX.XX.XX.XX'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What's your actual connection string look like? And does the user have permission to access from the IP you are at? For example, if I want to hit my db from home i need to add the user

```
me@12.345.67.890
```

OR for localhost

```
me@127.0.0.1
```

and give permission

then "me" would access

```
mysql -h <server ip> -u me -p <dbname>
```

that will prompt you to add the password

Comment: mysql database is working in ubuntu server. I used dbeaver tool to access the database in remote windows PC from ubuntu server.